# CSS Background image on Home Page only, in a Rails App

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently working on a Rails App, and am able to get an image as the background of the home page.  However, I placed the code in the homepage css file, but it is being applied to the application css file also.  This is resulting in the image being the background for all pages in the app.

In a Rails 3.1+ app, how do I get the background image to only appear on the homepage?

I have tried to move the background image css block to a different css file, but it still applied across all pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare styles inline for the page you want, if you declare in CSS file and you link those files in several documents than obviously it will take the background image for the respective element

Suppose it is like `index.html`

```
<style>
body {
   background-image: url('#');
}
</style>
```

Or simply declare a class and apply on that particular page

```
.unique { /* In Your CSS File */
   background-image: url('#');
}

<body class="unique"></body>
```

Comment: This makes sense, and I have tried this.  It partially works, the problem I am having is assignment of partials in Rails.  I think the question is more a Rails question, what is the best way to implement a seperate home page css.  A great example of this would be Michael Hartl's Rails tutorial https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_2nd_ed

Comment: How would change sample_app_2nd_ed / app / views / static_pages / home.html.erb to have a stand alone background, how would you change sample_app_2nd_ed / app / views / layouts / application.html.erb to accommodate.  Or is it best just to create another layout file and implement that to home.html.erb

Comment: If you have custom CSS body classes on each page in your site, you can easily namespace whatever styles to that particular page.

Comment: @rbynrls sorry dude, I just gave you a CSS solution, not aware about rails

Answer (score 1):

Use a class name on the body tag for that page only. Create a corresponding CSS declaration for that class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this but I solved this problem in one of my apps by making two application layouts, one for the home page `(home_application.html.erb`) and one for all other pages (`application.html.erb`). Put an id tag in your CSS file:

```
#home {
  background: url(example.jpg);
}
```

Make the `application.html.erb`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    header
  </head>

  <body>
    stuff
  </body>

</html>
```

Make the `home_application.html.erb`:

```
<body id="home">
    stuff
</body>
```

Then in your `static_pages_controller` (or whatever controller you use for your home page) put:

```
def home
    render 'layouts/home_application.html.erb'
end
```

This will render the layout with the background image for the home page and the layout for everything else for all other pages by only changing the id of the `<body>` tag.