# The code in my controller.css.scss file is being rendered instead of a background image?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to use a background image that spans the whole page for only the index view of my welcome controller, but the only thing being rendered is the code in my welcome.css.scss file.  The links that are supposed to be there are not being displayed or anything.

Here is my welcome.css.scss:

```
body {
background: {
  image: asset-url("sampleimage.jpeg");
  repeat: no-repeat;
 }
}
```

Welcome index view:

```
background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'sampleimage.jpg' %>)

<% content_for(:head) do %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'background' %>
<% end %>
```

Welcome controller:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
layout :resolve_layout

def index
end

def show
end

def about
end

def testimonials
end

private

def resolve_layout
case action_name
when "index"
  "background.css.scss"

else
  "application"
end
end


end
```

Thanks.

Comment: do you realy have `background.css.scss` layout? and `background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'sampleimage.jpg' %>)` in your `index.erb` without any tags?

Comment: Is it not supposed to be in the layout? and I added tags and it now says syntax error, unexpected tLABEL ...utBuffer.new; background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'sampleim... ... ^

Comment: I don't know where to start with this post. Overriding layout is being done incorrectly. You are telling it rather than use the application layout which is an `html.erb` file use a `css` sheet. This will not work `css` is not `html`. It will look for it in `/views/layouts` which is not where it is located. You are also including `css` styles directly in your view outside of a `style` block.`*= require_tree .` is probably still in `application.css` requiring all the sheets regardless.

Comment: Please read up on [layouts](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) and the [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) and see if you can figure this one out.

Comment: I originally had it working, but it didn't span the whole the page and I asked a question on here and now everything is a mess I guess.  Where can I learn how to do this.  Ive spent hours on Google and I can find next to nothing on backgrounds

Comment: Places to start [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144454/how-to-set-a-different-background-image-for-each-page-in-rails-3-site), [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13865610/css-background-image-on-home-page-only-in-a-rails-app), [Here](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-default-application-layout.html) or [Here](http://makandracards.com/makandra/2977-declare-different-css-background-images-for-different-locales) That should get you headed in the right direction. If you are going to use this layout multiple times then look into layouts.